# iFrame not loading in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, iframe

When a user logs into my web site I check to see if there are any active promotions, and if so I want to display a message in a popup iFrame.

This works in IE8 and IE9 but not FF or Chrome.

When using Chrome the page simply loops through the document.ready function...that is to say it executes the code in document.ready and showOpeningMessages() but no iFrame is displayed and then immediately drops back into document.ready and repeats the process as though the page was reloading.

Here is the code :

In C# code behind as part of the page load

```
            // session variable will be null to begin with to display message
        string promotionOpeningMessagesViewed = Session["promotionOpeningMessagesViewed"] == null ? "0" : "1";



        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
"pageScript", @"

function openingMessagesModalID()
{
    var id = '" + promotionOpeningMessagesPanel.ClientID + @"';
    return id;
}

function countOpeningMessages()
{
    var id = '" + mgr.PromotionOpeningMessageList.Count.ToString() + @"';
    return id;
}

function showOpeningMessages()
{
    $('#iframepromotionOpeningMessages').attr('src','PromotionOpeningMessages.aspx');
    document.getElementById('" + okayOpeningMessagesButton.ClientID + @"').style.display = 'block'; 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    if (countOpeningMessages() != '0' && '" + promotionOpeningMessagesViewed + @"' == '0') {
        document.getElementById('" + dummyButton.ClientID + @"').click();
    };
});

", true);
```

This is the markup :

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="promotionOpeningMessagesPanel" style="display:none;" CssClass="openingMessageBox" >
    <iframe id="iframepromotionOpeningMessages" frameborder="0" src="about:blank" style="border:none; width: 100%; height: 90%  "></iframe>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="okayOpeningMessagesButton" runat="server" 
                Text="<%$ Resources:UIText,  OK%>" 
                CssClass="buttons positive BtnAdd rightAlignButton"
                style="display:none;" />
     <asp:LinkButton ID="dummyButton" runat="server" 
                Text="<%$ Resources:UIText,  OK%>"
                CssClass="buttons positive BtnAdd"
                OnClientClick="showOpeningMessages();"
                style="display:none;" />
</asp:Panel>

<ajaxControlToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" 
    ID="promotionOpeningMessagesModalPopupExtender"
    BehaviorID="promotionOpeningMessagesModalPopupExtender"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    PopupControlID="promotionOpeningMessagesPanel" 
    RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
    OkControlID="okayOpeningMessagesButton"
    TargetControlID="dummyButton" />
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with c#. You need to post the generated html and any error messages that chrome's console prints out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided upon another route and reworked the code so it used the JQuery Popup Dialog API and this works much better.